# Multiple contact forms in a Plone website

Tags: python, plone, plone-4.x

I have `/contact-info`, as default contact page (http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/functionality/contactform.html) for my plone website.

I want to add a new contact page for a subfolder but with different settings (like from email address and fields).

I'm trying to create a new contact page using `Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_templates/contact-info.cpt` as model, but I think maybe it is a better way.

What is the easiest way to have multiple contact pages on a plone website?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplest way (no need of developing anything) is to install [PloneFormGen](http://plone.org/products/ploneformgen) and create a custom contact-info form with a **mailer adapter**.

Seems that new-way-dexterity-based [collective.easyform](http://collectiveeasyform.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) also provides same features (but never tested).

Comment: Agreed.  *.cpt is fairly old technology you don't want to learn if you don't have to

Comment: I created this contact form with PloneFormGen. Any idea how to set for it a different email address where the mails will be sent? For first one I use @@mail-controlpanel to set "Site 'From' address", but for this second form I need another email address.

Comment: SOLVED: using my-custom-contact/mailer/edit - fields: Recipient's full name and Recipient's e-mail address